# Partition of existing table with huge data in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-performance

I have a table which contains 2 cr records in table. I am trying to do its partition based on Month and Year.

I tried it with creating a filegroups of this tables but in my scenario that table is using on many places in pre coding part. Is there any way so I can partition this table and use it in BI reports so pre programming doesn't impact.

For edition : -
I have the following pretty basic query but it takes 10 mins to run.

Here is the execution plan - https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=B1dy0ZQ6d

Can anyone see a way of improving it? Let me know if some sample data/table structures would be useful.

E2E_TBL_LIQUIDITY_TRACKING_CFY_JUNE has 899556 records LQTFYOpeningStock has 934878 records E2E_TBL_CPL_SALES_MR_008 has 131491 records E2E_TBL_MATERIAL_MASTER has 4695 records LocationNameView has 477 records E2e_Tbl_Customer_Master has 20390 records E2e_Tbl_Lob_Master has 5 records

Below are indexes : -

```
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [Index1LQt] ON [dbo].[E2E_TBL_LIQUIDITY_TRACKING_CFY_JUNE]
(
    [Territory_Code] ASC
)
INCLUDE (   [Customer_Code],
    [Product_Code],[LOB_Code],[Distributor_Stock],[Dealers_Stock],[L3_Price],[L1_Price],[L2_Price]) 
    WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, SORT_IN_TEMPDB = OFF, DROP_EXISTING = OFF, ONLINE = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
GO


CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [Index2LQt] ON [dbo].[LQTFYOpeningStock]
(
    [Customer_Code] ASC,
    [Product_Code] ASC,
    [Territory_Code] ASC,
    [LOB_Code] ASC
)
INCLUDE (   [StockValueL1],
    [StockValueL2],
    [StockValueL3]) WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, SORT_IN_TEMPDB = OFF, DROP_EXISTING = OFF, ONLINE = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
GO

CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [Index3LQt] ON [dbo].[LQTFYOpeningStock]
(
    [Territory_Code] ASC
)
INCLUDE (   [Customer_Code],
    [Product_Code],
    [LOB_Code],
    [StockValueL1],
    [StockValueL2],
    [StockValueL3]) WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, SORT_IN_TEMPDB = OFF, DROP_EXISTING = OFF, ONLINE = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
GO



ALTER TABLE [dbo].[E2E_TBL_CPL_SALES_MR_008] ADD  CONSTRAINT [PK_MR008] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [Territory_Code] ASC,
    [Customer_Code] ASC,
    [Product] ASC,
    [SKU] ASC,
    [LOB] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, SORT_IN_TEMPDB = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ONLINE = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
```

Comment: What is a "cr"?

Comment: Also, according to the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/partitions/partitioned-tables-and-indexes?view=sql-server-ver15#processor-cores-and-number-of-partitions-guidelines), it's not recommended to have more partitions than there are cores on your CPU; maxing out at 64 (regardless of cores). This means you limit yourself to just over 5 years of partitions *if* you have a 64+ cores. Also, don't forget, partitions don't create themselves, so you'd have to create a new one each time you get to a new month.

Comment: Start at the beginning: why are you trying to partition anyway?

Comment: @Larnu Cr is crore .

Comment: @Charlieface I don't want to touch previous code , I need this partition for new report, Currently it is taking lot of time Because this is transactional table

Comment: OK so you want to partition for performance. Why do you think that partitioning improves performance? It's mainly designed for better management of bulk insert/delete. It sometimes can help query performance, but very often it doesn't help, and better indexing is usually worth looking at first. Modifying the query often helps also, but we can't help you without seeing your tables, indexes, query and execution plan

Comment: @Charlieface table has 10 Lakh records while selecting simply it is giving result in 46 sec but when i am using group by on one column its not coming in 5 min or 10 min like      Select Name, Code,Sum(ValueCol1),Sum(ValueCol2) from (Select  Name,Code,ValueCol1,ValueCol2,ValueCol3  from ABC LEFT OUTER JOIN DEF on DEF.Code=ABC.Code  Where Code in (1,2,4) ) M group by Name,Code

Comment: @Charlieface i have update my question for index and query plan

Comment: You have a number of implicit conversions which you should remove, and most worryingly, a very big table scan on `[E2E_TBL_PD_LOB]` (there's no clustered index for some reaosn) which also has an implicit conversion, so either it's not indexed, or the index is not being used. I would also be concerned about the final merge left join, which reduces the rows to 1, that should be earlier in the plan. You are also using a number of views which I don't have definitions for, they are probably not optimal. Anyway, partitioning is not relevant here, and the size of the big table also isn't really.

Comment: @Charlieface , https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=r1SRrM4au this the execution plan for LocationNameView in which i am using [E2E_TBL_PD_LOB] table E2E_Tbl_State_Master   24 rows  E2E_Tbl_Region_Master  123 rows  E2E_Tbl_Territory_Master 541 rows E2E_Tbl_Zone_Master 32 rows E2E_TBL_PD_LOB ZM     28   rows

Comment: I would need the definition for the view, not the plan. the plan would be for the whole query, which you gave already. But TBH this question is a bit too broad, there are too many things going on to be able to fix the performance issues. I've given you a few tips, but you need to work through the query and analyze it yourself, following the many tips you can find online such as https://sqlperformance.com, https://sql.kiwi, https://brentozar.com

Comment: @Charlieface Defination is : Select distinct SM.State_Code,SM.State_Name,TM.Territory_Code,TM.Territory_Name,RM.Region_Code,RM.Region_Name,ZM.Zone_Code,ZM.Zone_Name,PL.Location AllIndia_Name, ZM.Division_Code AllIndia_Code
from E2E_Tbl_State_Master SM With(Nolock),E2E_Tbl_Region_Master RM With(Nolock)
    ,E2E_Tbl_Territory_Master TM With(NoLock),E2E_Tbl_Zone_Master ZM WITH(Nolock)
 LEFT OUTER JOIN E2E_TBL_PD_LOB PL with(nolock)  On PL.India_Code=Convert(int,ZM.Division_Code)
Where SM.State_Code=RM.State_Code and TM.Region_Code=RM.Region_Code and ZM.Zone_Code=RM.Zone_Code

Answer (score 0):

You can partition without having multiple filegroups. Ideally (for performance reasons) each partition should be on a different filegroup on a different drive. But partitioning will work just fine (typically slower if the partitions are large_ on a single filegroup. Its easy to later move partitions between filegroups.

Comment: My problem is table is using in other place also like in transaction data like insert and update, So i want this table to split in month so performance wise in reports it will good without changes previous coding.

Comment: The data is split based on a function that you create. How the data is distributed has nothing to do with transactions. Once you set up a partitioned table the data in the table is inserted and selected with the same sql used for non-partitioned tables.